# Allow a user to embed a Google form into a blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-forms

I have a `ruby on rails` app with simple `erb` for the views. Users can create articles using a simple text editor that allows them to embed images and videos. However, I would like them to be able to insert a Google form that actually displays in the post content, not just a link. Hope it's possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There isn't any code I can show. I have a WYSIWIG editor that users can use to create blogs. They can attach images and videos as well. I would like to allow users to attach and display a Google form in the blog post. There is nothing I can find on the internet that provides any guidance.